# How to add a class to the ClassPath at runtime?

Tags: java

A have a `jar` file which has a `main` method. I compile a new class and I want to add this new class to CP.

```
/folder
  /my_jar_file.jar
  /MyClass.class
```

How can I do that kind of thing in Java without recompiling of jar file?

Comment: Just `-cp /folder/my_jar_file.jar`.

Comment: I got `Error: Could not find or load main class`. I 've specified in my jar file the main class with main method.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to class path is will not load your class at runtime.
You need to explicitly load your jar in the code as below,

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader (yourJar.toURL(), this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.company.abc", true, classLoader);
```